# Pythonic way to group by a pandas table

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table:

```
    dt  type    item
0   2021-02-08 20:43:15 Requesting  1111
1   2021-02-08 20:43:25 Response    1111
2   2021-02-08 20:43:15 Requesting  2222
3   2021-02-08 20:43:27 Response    2222
4   2021-02-08 20:43:16 Requesting  3333
5   2021-02-08 20:43:19 Response    3333
6   2021-02-08 20:43:16 Requesting  4444
7   2021-02-08 20:43:21 Response    4444
8   2021-02-08 20:43:16 Requesting  5555
9   2021-02-08 20:43:23 Failed      5555
8   2021-02-08 20:43:17 Requesting  5555
9   2021-02-08 20:43:29 Response    5555
```

It is already sorted by item and then second sort by time.

I want to do a group-by and get a new table that will have the amount of time it took between a request to the response, and another column for how many rows it included (so for item 5555 it took 4 rows)

What's a good pythonic way to do it?

Comment: Will an item only ever have a single request and response? This could be as simple as a `groupby` + `size` and `np.ptp`, but if you might have multiple times, or Failed rows outside of the request - response lines dealing with these possible edge cases will complicate the solution

Comment: I corrected the data to show a possible case. I am looking for the difference between the first request and the last response for each item (for the time between these rows, and the number of rows between them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your DataFrame is already sorted on Item and time, we just need to add a column that indicates the row number (with a simple `range(len(df))`)

Then we can groupby `head` and `tail` (also can `drop_duplicates` with `keep='first'` or `'last'`) to get the first request (time and row number) and the last response and subtract (aligning on `'item'`) to find the time difference and number of rows.

```
#df = df.sort_values(['item', 'dt'])
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'])
df['Nrows'] = range(len(df))

# First request row
reqs = (df.query('type == "Requesting"')
          .groupby('item').head(1)
          .set_index('item').drop(columns='type'))

# Last response row
resp = (df.query('type == "Response"')
          .groupby('item').tail(1)
          .set_index('item').drop(columns='type'))

result = resp - reqs
result['Nrows'] = result['Nrows']+1   # To get counting correct
```

---

```
                  dt  Nrows
item                       
1111 0 days 00:00:10      2
2222 0 days 00:00:12      2
3333 0 days 00:00:03      2
4444 0 days 00:00:05      2
5555 0 days 00:00:13      4
```

Comment: Perfect.Thank you very much, worked like a charm!